# Use mouse and keyboard at the same time

Tags: g1ant

Is it possibile to use mouse and mouse at the same time?

I have to select a few row in windows program. You can make in by holding <> and mouse.click on window element.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible. I prepared an example for you.

Open File Explorer window (for example Desktop folder) and make sure you have some files/folders there. `window` command will bring the window to the front.

Choose Insert/Mouse Position from the menu, click any file/folder in the File Explorer and choose "Yes" in the "Absolute position?" dialog that will be shown after you click on something on the screen.

Argument `type` with the value `down` means that the mouse button will be held pressed. Argument `button` with the value `right` means that it will be the right mouse button.

Use `keyboard` command to press `SHIFT` and add `down` keyword which means that the Shift button will be held pressed.

Then, "unclick" the right mouse button and "unclick" `SHIFT` like below by using the `up` keyword.

```
window ✱Desktop✱
mouse.click position ⟦point⟧653⫽608 relative false type down button right
keyboard ⋘SHIFT down⋙
mouse.click position ⟦point⟧653⫽608 relative false type up button right 
keyboard ⋘SHIFT up⋙
```

You can see that the automation works if a context menu appears with more options, for example "Copy as path".

You can do similar with your windows program.